# Deserve to or deserve to be

Tags: word-usage

I come across the following sentences-

- He deserves *to* pass.
- He deserves *to be* pass.

Would anyone tell me .. which is the correct one

Answer (score 1):

> He deserves to be pass

does not mean anything.

> He deserves to pass

is correct, as in "he deserves to pass a test because he has studied."